# Snapping options in QGIS 3.28.11 Firenze

Tags: qgis, mapping, snapping

I work with 60 layers in QGIS, I have to set the snapping for each layer to vertex & segment. Is there any way to set this snapping options for all layers in one time instead of doing this for the 60 layer each by each?

Answer (score 4):

Click on Project -----> Snapping Options,

[image]

this dialog will open:

[image]

Just click on the drop down list to chose if you want to apply the snapping on all the layers, or the active layer or chose "Advanced Configuration" if you want to set each layer separately.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are three mode in the project Snapping Setting :

- All Layer
- Active Layer
- Advanced Configuration

It seem that using all layer and selecting vertex and segment should work for you

[image]

[QGIS help on Snapping](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#snapping-and-digitizing-options)